# Starting the \parts environment with a different counter in exam class

Tags: numbering, counters, exam

I need to be able to start a parts environment at a later counter. For instance, starting with part `(b)` instead of `(a)`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{parts}
\part this is part a.
\end{parts}

\begin{parts}
\part This should be part b. 
\part This should be part c. 
\end{parts}
\end{document}
```

I've tried the ways to do it with the list packages, but they don't agree with the exam class. I've done my best to comb through the exam class document but didn't find anything.

Comment: `\setcounter{part}{1}` at the right position perhaps. (I assume, that `parts` environment resets the part counter?)

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `exam` class defines the `partno` counter, in order to achieve the startover at `(b)` the resetting of the `partno` counter has to be cheated by `setcounter{partno}{1}`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{parts}
\part this is part a.
\end{parts}

\begin{parts}
\setcounter{partno}{1}
\part This should be part b. 
\part This should be part c. 
\end{parts}
\end{document}
```

[image]