# How to end a \part properly and go back to the root level

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, parts

I want to use the `\part` command to have three different parts. Before the first part I have an abstract and an introduction. After the last part I wand to have the summary, the bibliography, the appendix and one more page on the same level as the parts before. While before the first part everything looks fine, somehow I struggle with finishing the last part.

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,DIV=15,BCOR=20mm,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
    pdfstartview=FitH,   
    pdffitwindow=true,
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=black,
    anchorcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
  ]{hyperref}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\mainmatter

\chapter{abstract}
\Blindtext

\chapter{introduction}
\Blindtext

\setpartpreamble{%
  \vspace*{40pt}%
  \blindtext
}

\part{Grundlagen}
\chapter{a1}
\Blindtext

\chapter{a2}
\Blindtext

\setpartpreamble{%
  \vspace*{40pt}%
  \blindtext
}
\part{Verwandte Arbeiten und Verfahren}
\chapter{b1}
\Blindtext

\chapter{b2}
\Blindtext

\setpartpreamble{%
  \vspace*{40pt}%
  \blindtext
}
\part{Applikation}

\chapter{c1}
\Blindtext

\chapter{summary}
\Blindtext

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{bibliography}
\Blindtext
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{appendix}
\Blindtext
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{some remaining meta information}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

This results in the following structure, both visually in the table of contents and when I open the content tab in a PDF viewer:

- abstract
- introduction
- Grundlagen

  - a1
  - a2
- Verwandte Arbeiten

  - b1
  - b2
- Applikation

  - c1
  - summary
  - bibliography
  - appendix
  - some remaining meta information

But I want this both as the structure which is shown in the PDF viewer when I click 'Content' and when I look in the generated table of contents page:

- abstract
- introduction
- Grundlagen

  - a1
  - a2
- Verwandte Arbeiten

  - b1
  - b2
- Applikation

  - c1
- summary
- bibliography
- appendix
- some remaining meta information

I am aware of other answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483396/how-to-explicitly-end-a-part-in-latex-with-hyperref (which looks quite hacky and I can not imagine that parts were meant to be used like that) or [How to proper end a part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266079/how-to-proper-end-a-part) (which uses a hand-crafted solution). But all of them do not look like a clean, neat solution. I would like to have something like an `\endpart` command. Now I even need to check whether the suggested `\bigskip` is the right thing to do for my layout. It looks like it is not but maybe I don't estimate distances well.

I am forced to use `scrbook`. A general solution would be perfect, a solution which suits to `scrbook` only is acceptable. As I can not use any other class, those suggestions are not valuable to me. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: PS: I also found a solution at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222447/starting-the-parts-environment-with-a-different-counter-in-exam-class#222453 but again it does not apply to srcbook, the used environment does not exist in my case.

Comment: In a similar setting I just introduced a part "Conclusions" for summary and similar things and elevated Appendix to a part.

Comment: I was asked to solve it the way I proposed, but generally speaking yours is a possible work-around.

Comment: For srcbook it seems like that there is no plan to end a part, see [this discussion in German](https://komascript.de/node/2138). The author of the class argues that you can not end a chapter or a section either without starting a new one.

Comment: By the way, for the distance before a `\part` in TOC you may look inside the `<main-file>.toc` file after compilation.

Comment: @OlegLobachev That does not help, because the distance is part of the `\l@part` definition not an explicit distance command in the `.toc` file. But the default distances (`beforeskip` settings) are documented in the `tocbasic` chapter of the KOMA-Script manual. But whether the part value or the part value minus the chapter value or something else is the correct value is hard to say and not a TeX problem but a typography problem.

Comment: What is so unclean about `\usepackage{bookmark}` and `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}`?

Comment: the unclean part is that I need to manually reset the bookmark and insert some space in the toc for a clear visual distinction. Having two commands for one logical step doesn't seem appropriate. And using `\bigskip` is kind of random. Following [this forum](https://komascript.de/node/2138) before a part the distance is `2.25em plus 1pt` and before a chapter `1em plus 1pt`. That means if I want to continue on the same level, for me `1.25em` would make sense but that is my personal opinion. If what I want happened more often, it could be standardized for all. But that doesn't seem to be the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further research and a [discussion with the author of KOMA-Script in German](https://komascript.de/node/2138) (in which `scrbook.cls` resides) has shown that there is no official way how to end a `\part`. It is simply not intended. Because of that [the hacky solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483396/how-to-explicitly-end-a-part-in-latex-with-hyperref) needs to be chosen, for the `scrbook` class of KOMA-Script I prefer a distance suiting to the given layout over `\bigskip`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,DIV=15,BCOR=20mm,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
    pdfstartview=FitH,   
    pdffitwindow=true,
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=black,
    anchorcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
  ]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bookmark}  
\usepackage{blindtext}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  level=\parttocdepth,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=0pt,
  beforeskip=.25em,
  entryformat=\nullfont,
  entrynumberformat=\nullfont,
  linefill=\relax,
  pagenumberformat=\nullfont,
]{part}{dummypart}
\newcommand*{\dummypart}{%
  \clearpage
  \addxcontentsline{toc}{dummypart}{}%
  \bookmarksetup{startatroot}
}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\mainmatter

\chapter{abstract}
\Blindtext

\chapter{introduction}
\Blindtext

\setpartpreamble{%
  \vspace*{40pt}%
  \blindtext
}

\part{Grundlagen}
\chapter{a1}
\Blindtext

\chapter{a2}
\Blindtext

\setpartpreamble{%
  \vspace*{40pt}%
  \blindtext
}
\part{Verwandte Arbeiten und Verfahren}
\chapter{b1}
\Blindtext

\chapter{b2}
\Blindtext

\setpartpreamble{%
  \vspace*{40pt}%
  \blindtext
}
\part{Applikation}

\chapter{c1}
\Blindtext

\dummypart

\chapter{summary}
\Blindtext

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{bibliography}
\Blindtext
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{appendix}
\Blindtext
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{some remaining meta information}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

That looks like the best solution I could find.

Comment: Note [this comment by Markus](https://komascript.de/comment/5637#comment-5637)  (and his suggestion) on the KOMA-Script website.

Comment: Using correct penalties as it is pointed out in the comment is a good point. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: `addxcontentsline` seems to add an extra (blank) empty to the PDF bookmarks

Comment: But using `\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-2}%` before it seems to resolve that.